# Can I remove the SSD cache from a laptop and sill have a functioning machine?

Tags: ssd, hardware-failure, hard-drive-cache

I have an old [Asus laptop](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Asus-VivoBook-S400CA-CA006H.100413.0.html) which came with a 500 GB HDD and a 24 GB SSD cache. These two parts got damaged and need to be replaced. However I was wondering if I can do without the SSD cache; specifically I wonder if there could be issues of data corruption or system failure if I decide not to replace the SSD.

My understanding is that the SSD cache provides performance improvement, but I don't know if it is absolutely vital for the correct functioning of the machine. The thing is that this is an old laptop and the SSD costs as much as the hard drive, so I don't know if it is worth the investment.

Comment: Nowadays SSDs got so cheap, just remove SSD and HDD and just buy a 500GB SSD instead (should cost about 50 euro/USD).

Answer (score 0):

'Fusion' drives were a stopgap for when SSDs cost an arm & a leg. They were very marginally faster than HDs, due to the SSD attached being used as a cache to the HD.
They are no longer worth the effort now SSD prices have fallen dramatically.

Just buy a single SSD, as large as you need/can afford. Your machine will be very noticeably faster.